# How to make an image clickable within span button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a span within a button clickable. The span has a .png image within it. It will only act as a button when I click around the actual image, but not when I click on the image itself. I cant find any solutions that directly relates to my issue.

HTML

```
<button id="btn3"><span class"btn3"></span></button>
```

CSS

```
span.btn3 {
    background: url("./images/raincloud.png") no-repeat top left;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Edit:

Here is the JS function. It is meant to change the audio/video file when a certain button is clicked.

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('btn'),
function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    switch (e.target.id) {
      case "btn3":
        video.src = "./video/rain2.mp4";
        video.play();
        break;
      case "btn4":
        video.src = "./video/rain1.mp4";
        video.play();
        break;
      case "btn5":
        audio.src = "./audio/rain.mp4";
        audio.play();
        break;
      case "btn6":
        audio.src = "./audio/rain2.mp4";
        audio.play();
        break;
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Missing `=`in `class="btn3"`
- You want the ID of the parent of the target
- your forEach is not very convincing. I delegate instead from the nearest container

```js
const audio = document.getElementById("audio");
const video = document.getElementById("video");
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName == "SPAN") {
    var id = tgt.closest("button").id;
    console.log(id)
    switch (id) {
      case "btn3":
        video.src = "./video/rain2.mp4";
        video.play();
        break;
      case "btn4":
        video.src = "./video/rain1.mp4";
        video.play();
        break;
      case "btn5":
        audio.src = "./audio/rain.mp4";
        audio.play();
        break;
      case "btn6":
        audio.src = "./audio/rain2.mp4";
        audio.play();
        break;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span.btn3 {
  background: url(https://img.icons8.com/cotton/2x/cloud.png) no-repeat top left;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="btn3"><span class="btn3"></span></button>
  <button id="btn3"><span class="btn3"></span></button>
  <button id="btn4"><span class="btn3"></span></button>
  <button id="btn5"><span class="btn3"></span></button>
</div>
<audio id="audio" />
<video id="video" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I fixed that but still the same problem. I can click the image and the pointer comes up when I hover over it, but it wont run the function. I've added the JS function to the top if that helps.

Comment: Perfect! Works just as I wanted! Thanks so much. Do you mind explaining why my code wasnt working?

Comment: 1. The id was on the button 2. assuming your addEventlistener worked, the click was on the span

Answer (score -1):

Add the onClick property via JavaScript to the span element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

HTML

```
<button id="btn3"><span class="btn3" id="span_in_button"></span></button>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('span_in_button').onclick = function changeContent() {

   // Your functionality here.

}
```

or by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

or add onclick property directly into the HTML span element https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_onclick.asp

in HTML body:

```
<button id="btn3"><span class="btn3" onclick="myFunction()"></span></button>
```

in HTML head:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    // Your functionality here.
}
</script>
```